# OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed after changing certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, single-sign-on, saml

After changing the certificate for SAML authentication in a service provider-initiated SSO environment, some users experiencing this error: `OpenSSL::PKey::RSAError: padding check failed`. Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: It's likely a signature validation error, but that's nowhere near enough information to diagnose. You should reproduce and gather logging.

Comment: I tried to parse the SAML response with the old private key, and although it wasn't valid anymore it didn't throw this error. Does this mean the client isn't using the updated XML metadata? @AndrewK.

Comment: Which certificate did you change? is it signing/encryption cert at IDP or encryption cert at SP? For certs changes at IDP, your SP must refresh the IDP metadata. And if certs are changed at SP, then your IDP must refresh the SP metadata.